# Recursive Dictionaries in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have small structures like this:

```
let arguments = [ "a" : [ "b" : [ "c" : "d", "e" : "f", "g" : "h" ] ] ]
```

In Swift 2 I could pass them as NSDictionary parameter to other functions. Now its all error. Swift wants me to specify precisely the Dictionary types but since the structures vary its not possible. How to solve this?

Comment: Why can't you declare the type? `[ String : [ String : [ String : String ]]]`?

Comment: Try to change the dictionary parameters in the *other functions* to Swift types, the most common but specified type of a Swift `Dictionary` is `[String:Any]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can still pass a dictionary to a function in Swift 3.

### If the dictionary structure is known

In this case, as suggested by *sbarow* just declare the dictionary type in the param of the function

```
let arguments = [ "a" : [ "b" : [ "c" : "d", "e" : "f", "g" : "h" ] ] ]

func foo(dict: [String: [String: [String: String]]]) {
    print(dict)
}

foo(dict:arguments)
```

### If the dictionary structure is unknown

In this case, if you only know your dictionary has a `String` as key then you can declare it like shown below

```
let arguments = [ "a" : [ "b" : [ "c" : "d", "e" : "f", "g" : "h" ] ] ]

func foo(dict: [String: Any]) {
    print(dict)
}

foo(dict:arguments)
```